# Uncaught TypeError: Return value of Magento\InventoryComposerInstaller must be an instance of Magento\InventoryComposerInstaller\void, none returned

Tags: php, magento, composer-php, magento2

I am trying to install Magento 2 via composer on my web server. After having to add the following in to the composer.json file in order to get everything working off a level playing field with the version of php being used:

```
"config": {
    "platform": {
        "php": "7.2.14"
    }
}
```

I then start getting things to happen when I `composer install`:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 392 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing magento/magento-composer-installer (0.1.13): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.10.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.10.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing zendframework/zend-stdlib (2.7.7): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing zendframework/zend-hydrator (1.1.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing psr/container (1.0.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing container-interop/container-interop (1.2.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing zendframework/zend-validator (2.11.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing zendframework/zend-escaper (2.6.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing zendframework/zend-uri (2.6.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing psr/http-message (1.0.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing zendframework/zend-diactoros (1.8.6): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing zendframework/zend-loader (2.6.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing zendframework/zend-http (2.8.4): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing zendframework/zend-psr7bridge (0.2.2): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing zendframework/zend-servicemanager (2.7.11): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing zendframework/zend-filter (2.9.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing zendframework/zend-inputfilter (2.10.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing zendframework/zend-form (2.13.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing zendframework/zend-eventmanager (2.6.4): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing zendframework/zend-code (3.3.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing zendframework/zend-console (2.7.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing zendframework/zend-mvc (2.7.15): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing zendframework/zend-math (2.7.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing zendframework/zend-crypt (2.6.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing tedivm/jshrink (v1.3.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing symfony/process (v4.1.11): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing symfony/console (v4.1.11): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing oyejorge/less.php (v1.7.0.14): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing psr/log (1.1.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing monolog/monolog (1.24.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing magento/zendframework1 (1.14.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing symfony/finder (v4.2.3): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing symfony/filesystem (v4.2.3): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing seld/phar-utils (1.0.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing seld/jsonlint (1.7.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing justinrainbow/json-schema (5.2.8): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing composer/xdebug-handler (1.3.2): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing composer/spdx-licenses (1.5.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing composer/semver (1.4.2): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing composer/ca-bundle (1.1.4): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing composer/composer (1.8.4): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing colinmollenhour/credis (1.10.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract (v1.4.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing magento/framework (102.0.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing magento/inventory-composer-installer (1.0.3): Downloading (100%)  
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Return value of Magento\InventoryComposerInstaller\Plugin::initModuleDeployment() must be an instance of Magento\InventoryComposerInstaller\void, none returned in /var/www/vhosts/blah/project-community-edition/vendor/magento/inventory-composer-installer/src/Plugin.php:69
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/blah/project-community-edition/vendor/magento/inventory-composer-installer/src/Plugin.php(88): Magento\InventoryComposerInstaller\Plugin->initModuleDeployment()
#1 /var/www/vhosts/blah/project-community-edition/vendor/magento/inventory-composer-installer/src/Plugin.php(82): Magento\InventoryComposerInstaller\Plugin->getModuleDeployment()
#2 [internal function]: Magento\InventoryComposerInstaller\Plugin->onPackageChange(Object(Composer\Installer\PackageEvent))
#3 phar:///usr/lib/plesk-9.0/composer.phar/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(176): call_user_func(Array, Object(Composer\Installer\PackageEvent))
#4 phar:///usr/lib/plesk-9.0/comp in /var/www/vhosts/blah/project-community-edition/vendor/magento/inventory-composer-installer/src/Plugin.php on line 69

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Return value of Magento\InventoryComposerInstaller\Plugin::initModuleDeployment() must be an instance of Magento\InventoryComposerInstaller\void, none returned in /var/www/vhosts/blah/project-community-edition/vendor/magento/inventory-composer-installer/src/Plugin.php:69
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/blah/project-community-edition/vendor/magento/inventory-composer-installer/src/Plugin.php(88): Magento\InventoryComposerInstaller\Plugin->initModuleDeployment()
#1 /var/www/vhosts/blah/project-community-edition/vendor/magento/inventory-composer-installer/src/Plugin.php(82): Magento\InventoryComposerInstaller\Plugin->getModuleDeployment()
#2 [internal function]: Magento\InventoryComposerInstaller\Plugin->onPackageChange(Object(Composer\Installer\PackageEvent))
#3 phar:///usr/lib/plesk-9.0/composer.phar/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(176): call_user_func(Array, Object(Composer\Installer\PackageEvent))
#4 phar:///usr/lib/plesk-9.0/comp in /var/www/vhosts/blah/project-community-edition/vendor/magento/inventory-composer-installer/src/Plugin.php on line 69
```

I have had no luck searching around for help with this issue linked with Magento. Some similar issues linked with Composer, but not Magento, had user requests for further information on the composer versions and php versions etc. Below is the information requested in those threads:

```
$ composer --version
Composer version 1.9-dev (blah) 2019-02-08 16:02:33

$ composer show composer/composer | grep versions
versions : * 1.8.4

$ composer depends composer/composer
magento/framework  102.0.0  requires  composer/composer (^1.6)

$ php -version
PHP 7.0.32-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) ( NTS )
```

PHP version in Plesk: 7.2.14

PHP version listed in phpinfo(): 7.2.14

At the moment I am stumped as to how to proceed with this issue. Any advice or pointers would be greatly appreciated. This is my first experience of installing by Composer, and I typically try to stay clear of command line stuff due to lack of understanding/experience with linux/bash etc.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should change the CLI version to PHP 7.2 as well. That package seems to be using PHP 7.1 as a minimum version (since they are using the the return type `void` in their code which wasn't introduced until PHP 7.1).

Comment: Thanks @MagnusEriksson, I will speak to the hosts. We had discussed the CLI version previously however the hosts had indicated that the addition of specifying the php version in the composer.conf file should fix php version incompatibilities. The worry was the possible impact of other websites (namely the M1 instance I am wanting to move to this M2 install) already using the CLI.

Comment: The issue is that composer is a PHP package, which is run using PHP. So it would need to read the composer file using PHP before it can know what PHP version it should use. I'm not sure how your host handles that, but it sounds a bit odd.

Comment: The platform config can be used to tell Composer which PHP version to assume when resolving dependencies. However this should only be used to force an older PHP version for cases where Composer is executed with a more recent PHP versions than the one that later executes the application. So in your case you could set it to the older PHP version (i.e. 7.0.32).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error can be realted to **PHP compatibility** :

- For `Magento 2.3.1+` : `PHP 7.1` or `PHP 7.2`
- For `Magento 2.3.0` : `PHP 7.1`
- For `Magento 2.2` : `PHP 7.1` or `PHP 7.0`
- For `Magento 2.1` : `PHP 7.1`, `PHP 7.0` or `PHP 5.6`
- For `Magento 2.0` : `PHP 7.0`, `PHP 5.6` or `PHP 5.5`

Check your PHP version, and upgrade or downgrade PHP if needed.

**You will never make Magento 2 works fine without the good version of PHP**

Comment: Thanks for the response to you and those that commented on my question. It seems I was misled as to the impact specifying the webserver php version in the composer.conf file would have. I downgraded my webserver php to a version that matched my server CLI php version (7.0.32) and installed Magento 2.2.7 without any further error or issue. At a later date I will look to upgrading the CLI php version and then I will be able to upgrade Magento to the latest version.

Comment: This answer is now false, even if yes: read compatibility issues. Magento 2.3.1, published in March 2019, is compatible PHP 7.2.

Comment: @PolRavalitera, thanks for your comment. You are right, I just edit my answer.